# Migration nullable field causing issues

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a migration called 'create_modules_table' see code below.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();            
        });
    }
```

I have added a FK 'course_id'. Without 'nullable' i faced an error relating to 'course_id' not having a default value. So i added 'nullable'. However now it is throwing me further problems, when i create a new module and select the course to attach to the module, the field in the DB is null (despite selecting an existing course from my form). I have added an image for context. Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong? I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.[image]

Module.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Module extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'course_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
    ];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id');
    }
}
```

ModulesController;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Module;
use App\Course;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ModulesController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $modules = new module();
        if ($request->input('course_id')) {
            $modules = $modules->where('course_id', $request->input('course_id'));
        }

        $modules = $modules->all();
        return view('admin.module.index', compact('modules'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $courses = Course::all()->pluck('title', 'id');

        return view('admin.module.create', compact('courses'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $module = Module::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.modules.index', ['course_id' => $request->id]); //redirects to correct route by adding course_id in parameter 

    }

}
```

create.blade.php;

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create Module</div>
                <div class="card-body">

                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.modules.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required" for="name">Module Title</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="id" required>
                                    @if($errors->has('name'))
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        {{ $errors->first('name') }}
                                    </div>
                                    @endif
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('Courses', 'Course', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                                {!! Form::select('Course[]', $courses, Request::get('Course'), ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!} 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
@endsection
```

index.blade.php;

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>

                <a href="{{ route('admin.modules.create') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create Module</button></a>

            </p>
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Modules</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Module Title</th>
                            <th>Course Title</th>
                            <th>Instructor</th> 
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($modules as $key => $module)
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{ $module->id }}</th>
                            <td>{{ $module->title }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $module->course->title ?? ''}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I would like to add there is no error, the DB is simply not displaying an input.. for some reason. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your form there is no field named `course_id`, instead you've a field with name `Course[]` which is a multi-select, so in your `store method` when you are using `Module::create($request->all());` there is no field matching in your `$fillable` array in the `Module` model, so you need to map fields manually and also, since you are using an array (because multi-select produces array), you need to use single element from the array to create a relation.

So, one easy approach could be ():

```
Module::create([
    'title' => $request->input('title'),
    'course_id' => reset($request->input('course')) // get the first item from array
]);
```

I think your are missing something, you should not use a `multi-select` for a foreign key unless you've a `many-to-many` relation and in that case you'll create/attach multiple related entries in a pivot table.